# slick carousel - trying to minimize the number of dom elements

Tags: javascript, carousel

I'm using slick carousel to try and display a bunch of images (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). The library works very well, but all examples have all the slides baked right into the dom. This approach doesn't work very well for me because I want to be able to scroll through many, many images and adding them all to the dom isn't possible (or performant).

Two approaches look like they might work:

1) Have a fixed number of slides, say 3, and use the `onAfterScroll` callback to cycle my photo s through my 3 elements and use `slickGoTo` to move the slick index. This approach seems to work but I'm getting some weird rendering artifacts when i use `slickGoTo`

2) Use `slickAdd` and `slickRemove` to append and prepend elements to the dom as I scroll. Unfortunately, prepending elements seems to change the current slide property in slick which screws everything up. This approach seems like it has the most potential, if it only worked.

Has anyone tried either of these approaches and had any success?

Thanks!

Comment: the library has a lazy loading option, have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Just as user2943490 mentioned:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slick-slider').slick({
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
});
```

You’ll see the first three images. Image number four won’t be loaded until you navigate to the next slide.

Comment: I have used the lazyload option in my existing slider which needs to be autoplayed:

    ```lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
 infinite: true,
 slidesToShow: 5,
 slidesToScroll: 5,
 dots: true,
 arrows: true,
 autoplay: true,
 autoplaySpeed: 2000,```

@Flax I want to resolve the issue "Avoid excessive DOM size" in lighthouse audit. Above change does not break anything but also doesnt help improve the performance. How do I know if it's working?